# Are these two naive upper bounds ok?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

EDIT:

Is my work ok?  Here, I am trying to show a  uniform bound for the sum of $cos(n)$

$$|\sum_{n=1}^{N} cos(n)|$$
$$=\big |\sum \frac{e^{in} + e^{-in}}{2}\big|$$
$$\le \sum |\frac{e^{in} + e^{-in}}{2}|$$
$$\le \sum |\frac{e^{in}}{2}| + \sum |\frac {e^{-in}}{2}|$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \sum |(e^i)^n| +  \frac{1}{2} \sum |(e^{-i})^n|$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} |\frac {e^i-e^{i(N+1)}}{1-e^i}| + \frac{1}{2} |\frac {e^{-i}-e^{-i(N+1)}}{1-e^{-i}}|$$
$$\le \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-e^i}+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-e^i} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-e^{-i}} +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-e^{-i}}$$

Specifically, my concern is that I am not sure whether I am showing the upper bound of one of the factors correctly, in applying the Dirichlet Test.

For example, is this ok

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(n) \right|
    \le \sum_{n=1}^N \left|\cos(n)\right|
    \le \sum_{n=1}^N 1
    \le N$$

And so $\sum \cos(n)$ has bounded partial sums for every positive integer $N$.  My gut feeling is that this is not true, and seems like a naive "bound".  But, it could be true, because $N$ is fixed, before giving the estimate.

A second example would be

$$\left|\int_1^R e^{ix}dx\right|
     \le \int_1^R \left|e^{ix}\right|dx
     \le \int_1^R 1 dx = R-1$$

which I claim is a "uniform bound" for any $R$ fixed.  The bound certainly looks independent of $x$.

Are both of my examples ok?

Thanks,

Comment: It depends on what you need. If for example $R$ is *fixed*, then the second calculation is adequate. But we can (and probably need to) do much better, and obtain a bound *independent* of $R$. This can be done, integrate explicitly. For the discrete version, look at the sum $\sum_1^N e^{in}$, a geometric series.

Comment: It depends,on what sense "okay" has for your application.  Certainly these are valid arguments, and your use of "naive" suggests you may be satisfied with the over-estimation that results. The word "uniform" however suggests the opposite.  It doesn't make sense in the second example to claim the bound is uniform because "independent of $x$" since $x$ is a bound variable having no value outside the definite integral where it appears.

Comment: Hi @AndréNicolas, I just edited my question to show my work for $\sum cos(n)$.  What do you think?  It looks weird.  Should I convert the last bound into sines and cosines, or is that not necessary?  Thanks,

Comment: Regarding your edit, notice that you are in trouble by the 4th line, because $|e^{in}/2| = 1/2$ so $\sum_{n=1}^{N}|e^{in}/2| = N/2$. You need to avoid moving the absolute values inside the sum at this point, because you give away too much by doing that.

Comment: Also, the second-to-last line does not follow from the one before it, and the last line is definitely not right because $1/(1-e^{i})$ etc. are not even real numbers.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response, @Bungo.  I was finding it tricky to understand using the trig identities, so I was hoping to keep the exponentials for as long as possible.  You're right that this doesn't work.  I'll try again...

Comment: Your second-to-last line is actually OK if you get rid of the stuff before it. Now you can do the following: $$\left|\frac{e^{i} - e^{i(N+1)}}{1-e^i}\right| \leq \left|\frac{e^i}{1-e^i}\right|  + \left|\frac{e^{i(N+1)}}{1-e^i}\right| = \frac{1}{|1-e^i|} + \frac{1}{|1-e^i|} = \frac{2}{|1-e^i|}$$ Now you can write the denominator as $|1 - \cos(1) - i\sin(1)| = \sqrt{(1-\cos(1))^2 + (\sin(1))^2} \geq \sqrt{\sin(1)^2} = |\sin(1)|$, so the expression above is $\leq 2/|\sin(1)|$.

Comment: Oh! that's so cool :-)  I will try this now :-) @Bungo

Comment: Or, for that matter, $\sqrt{(1-\cos(1))^2 + (\sin(1))^2} = \sqrt{1 - 2\cos(1) + \cos^2(1) + \sin^2(1)} = \sqrt{2 - 2\cos(1)}$, which will give you a tighter (but more complicated-looking) bound. Not that it matters - any finite bound that does not depend on $N$ will work equally well.

Comment: Ah, I had gotten to that step in one of my many (messy) attempts but stopped at the L.H.S. of your equation.  Thanks for showing the expansion to use $cos^2(1) + sin^2(1) = 1$.  Can I ask you one last question @Bungo?  For the integral of $e^{ix}$, from $1$ to $R$, integrating it directly gives me $-ie^{iR} + ie^i$, so it's absolute value, using the triangle inequality, is bounded above by 2.  This bound is independent of $R$ (so there are no issues with the improper integral, letting $R \to \infty$.)  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001: The bound $|\int_1^R e^{ix} dx| = |-ie^{iR} + ie^i| \leq 2$ is correct and as you said, it doesn't depend on $R$, so it qualifies as a uniform bound. Looks good!

Comment: Ok awesome, thanks so much for your time and help @Bungo - really appreciate it :-)  A quick check on Wolfram shows that the integral doesn't converge, but that's what the other factor is for, I am guessing (the monotonically decreasing factor).  I will proceed with my work now, but learning how to show the uniform bounds properly was the key point. Thanks and have a great night, Bungo!  :-)

Comment: @User001: That's right, $\int_1^{\infty} e^{ix} dx$ itself does not converge, but since it remains bounded, $\int_1^{\infty}e^{ix}f(x) dx$ will converge if $f$ is monotonically decreasing to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(n)\right| \leq N$$
is certainly true, it is not likely to be of much use for the Dirichlet test, which requires a bound that is independent of $N$.

We can obtain a better bound by recognizing that $\cos(n) = (e^{in} + e^{-in})/2$, and for any nonzero integer $k$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{ikn} &= e^{ik}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{ikn}\right)\\
& = e^{ik}\left(\frac{e^{ikN} - 1}{e^{ik} - 1} \right) \\
&= e^{ik}\left( \frac{e^{ikN/2}}{e^{ik/2}}\right)\left( \frac{e^{ikN/2}-e^{-ikN/2}}{e^{ik/2}-e^{-ik/2}}\right) \\
&= e^{ik} \left(\frac{e^{ikN/2}}{e^{ik/2}}\right)\left(\frac{2i\sin(kN/2)}{2i\sin(k/2)}\right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
where we have used the fact that $e^{ix} - e^{-ix} = 2i\sin(x)$. Taking absolute values, we get
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{ikn}\right| = \left|\frac{\sin(kN/2)}{\sin(k/2)}\right|$$
Applying this result with $k=1$ and $k=-1$, we obtain
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(n)\right| &= \frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(e^{in} + e^{-in})\right| \\
 &\leq \frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{in} \right| + \frac{1}{2} \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{-in} \right|\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{\sin(N/2)}{\sin(1/2)}\right| + \frac{1}{2}\left|\frac{\sin(-N/2)}{\sin(-1/2)}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{\sin(N/2)}{\sin(1/2)}\right| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{|\sin(1/2)|} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Hi @Bungo, how do you get the $sin(N/2)$ and $sin(1/2)$?

Comment: @User001: I added some more details to the calculation. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Definitely, +1.

Answer (score 2):

The first bound you have will not work for the Dirichlet test; we need a bound that is independent of $N$.  The easiest approach is to explicitly calculate this sum by noting that
$$
\cos(n) = \Re (\cos(1) + i\sin(1))^n
$$
and apply the formula for the sum of a geometric series.  Then, find an upper bound for the numerator.

Comment: Thanks so much @Omnomnomnom :-)